# Fourier series for piecewise function

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

let $-\pi \leq x\leq \pi$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x-\pi, & \text{ if}  -\pi \leq x\leq -\pi/ 2\\
\;\;\;x, & \text{ if } -\pi/2 \leq x\leq \pi/2\\
-x+\pi, & \text{ if } \pi/2 \leq x\leq \pi\end{cases}$$

it's easy to see that $f$ is odd so $a_0=a_n=0$ and $b_k=2\int _0^{\pi}f(x)\sin(kx)$for all positive integers $n$.

To compute $b_k$ I use the following auxiliar computations: [aux 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20xsin%28nx%29dx%20from%200%20to%20pi/2), [aux2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28-x%2bpi%29sin%28nx%29dx%20%20from%20pi/2%20to%20pi)

and get $b_k=\frac{4}{k^2}\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)$.

So the fourier series should be $$\sum _{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4}{k^2}\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)\sin(kx)$$
 but when I check for $x=\pi /2$ [I get $\pi ^2/2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%20%284/k%5E2%29sin%28kpi/2%29sin%28k%2a%28pi/2%29%29%20%29%20from%20k=1%20to%20%2binf) instead of $\pi /2$. It also fails [for $x=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%20%284/k%5E2%29sin%28kpi/2%29sin%28k%2a%281%29%29%20%29%20from%20k=1%20to%20%2binf) which seems to yield $\pi$ (I did a finite sum for this one because wolfram alpha cant find the sum of the series). And for $x=\pi$ it gives $0$ instead of $\pi$. EDIT: I just realised it supposed to give $0$ instead of $\pi$, so there's nothing wrong at $x=\pi$. Second EDIT: I did a mistake in the input in wolfram alpha. I now updated the links

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: because of not enough reputation I can't post more than 2 links. can someone please fix? thanks

Comment: Thanks, anonymous, for taking the time to format!

Comment: This is just a triangular wave.

Comment: @amWhy thank you for the help.

Comment: @ZettaSuro is that supposed to help me somehow? can you elaborate?

Comment: You checked for $ x=\pi ^2/2 $ or $ x=\pi /2 $? Your last paragraph is not clear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal my bad. I fixed it

Comment: @anonymous: I think you know what the correct value should be.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I don't know what you mean. for $x=\pi /2$ I think I should get $\pi /2$. is this correct?

Comment: @anonymous: Yes, you are right, since the function is continuous at this point. You may have done a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: I forgot to divide by the period: $\pi$! AGAIN!

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what's from when in this question. If there is still a problem, please rewrite the question to make clear what the problem that you want solved is.